# form not showing in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to create form in Django 
There is no error in the source code
and the program is running
but when the signup page is run the form does not appear and there appears "RegestrationonData object (None)"

this source code

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class RegestrationonData(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

form.py

```
from django import forms

class RegestrationonForm (forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse, render, redirect

from .models import News
from .models import RegestrationonData

def Index(request):
    context = {
        "name": "Ali"
    }

    return render(request, "index.html",  context)


def Home(request):
    obj = News.objects.filter()
    context = {
        "list": ["Django", "Flask", "Oddo"],
        "data": obj
    }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)


def Contact(request):
    return render(request, "contact.html")


def NewsDate(request, year):
    article_list = News.objects.filter(pub_date__year=year)
    context = {
        'year': year,
        'article_list': article_list
    }
    return render(request, "NDate.html", context)


def SignUp(request):
    context = {
        "form": RegestrationonData
    }

    return render(request, "signup.html", context)
```

signup.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
{% block title %} Sign Up {% endblock %} 
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
  <h1>This is sign up page</h1>
  <form>
    {{form}}
  </form>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

when running the application
[image]

any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `RegestrationonForm`(Form class) not `RegestrationonData`(Model class)

```
from form import RegestrationonForm


def SignUp(request):
    context = {
        "form": RegestrationonForm
    }
    # rest of the code
```